# Is it okay to ask about folk saying and how they came about?

Tags: discussion

For example, would it be okay to ask a question like, " where did the term caught "red handed" come from?". I think it could be a possible subjective question and that's why I'm checking to see if it okay to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are asking about an English term, you are much more likely to get a good answer from the [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) stack. They field questions like that all the time (and have their OED's at the ready), and are a fully-graduated stack.